# read and fetch data from MongoDB Py spark at same time

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

So i am working on a project where multiple users will be writing to mongodb database here i am taking the system metrics of the user's computer or laptop or iot device

```py
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi
import generatedata
import time

uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.1.1"

# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# show all databases
print(client.list_database_names())

# create new database named networkmetrics
db = client["networkmetrics"]

# creating collection
siddhu = db["siddhu"]

# Get the last _id in the collection
last_id = siddhu.find_one(sort=[("_id", -1)])
if last_id is None:
    counter = 0
else:
    counter = last_id["_id"] + 1

def push_data():
    global counter
    cpu, memory, disk, network, timenow = generatedata.get_system_metrics()
    data = {"_id": counter, "cpu": cpu, "memory": memory, "disk": disk, "network": network, "timenow": timenow}
    siddhu.insert_one(data)
    print("Data inserted successfully")
    counter += 1

# Run the push_data function every second for 10 minutes
end_time = time.time() + 50
while time.time() < end_time:
    push_data()
```

this inserts the data to mongodb on the collection name **siddhu** what i want is that i want to connect to this always updating database and process the data at the same time taken the window of 5 seconds

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import time

print(pyspark.__version__)

# create a spark session and connect to mongo db on the database name networkmetrics and on collection names "all" and "all2"
conf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
.set("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
.setMaster("local[*]") \
.setAppName("pythonspark") \
.setAll([('spark.driver.memory', '4g'), ('spark.executor.memory', '6g'), ('spark.cores.max', '3')])

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlC = SQLContext(sc)
mongo_ip = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/networkmetcdrics."

last_id = -1
while True:
    siddhu = sqlC.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", mongo_ip + "siddhu").load()
    siddhu.createOrReplaceTempView("siddhu")
    batch = sqlC.sql(f"SELECT * FROM siddhu WHERE _id > {last_id} ORDER BY _id LIMIT 5")
    if batch.count() < 5:
        time.sleep(3)
        print("siddhu system offline")
        break
    avg_cpu = batch.agg({"cpu": "avg"}).collect()[0][0]
    avg_memory = batch.agg({"memory": "avg"}).collect()[0][0]
    print(f"Average CPU: {avg_cpu}, Average Memory: {avg_memory}")
    last_id = batch.agg({"_id": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
    time.sleep(5)
```

i am not able to run this code i have tried other methods of putting new variable to the instead of directly using the _id field etc but nothing works what am i doing wrong here ??? i am technically new to spark and mongodb but i am having a little bit good hold on python when i ran the program at same time each file on different terminal i am running into error how to fix it ?